# How to embed Yaws with SSL?

Tags: yaws

I'd like to embed yaws with ssl, but it shows error message, Can anyone tell me how to set SSL property ?

Below is my code

```
Id = "my_server",
GconfList = [{logdir, "/Users/james/Documents/workspaces/erlang/embed_yaws/log"},
           {ebin_dir, ["/Users/james/Documents/workspaces/erlang/embed_yaws/ebin"]},
           {id, Id}],
Docroot = "/Users/james/Documents/workspaces/erlang/embed_yaws/www",
SconfList = [
        {docroot, Docroot},
        {port, 4444},
        {listen, {0,0,0,0}},
        {ssl,[{keyfile, "/Users/james/Develop/yaws-2.0.2/etc/yaws/yaws-key.pem"},
          {certfile, "/Users/james/Develop/yaws-2.0.2/etc/yaws/yaws-cert.pem"},
          {depth,0},{dhfile,"/Users/james/Develop/yaws-2.0.2/etc/yaws/dhparams.pem"}]},
        {appmods, [{"/rest", myappmod1, []},{"/ws", myws, []}]}
        ],
yaws:start_embedded(Docroot, SconfList, GconfList, Id)
```

The Partial Error Message is below

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Oct-2015::17:10:17 ===
FATAL: {noproc,
       {gen_server,call,
           ......

=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Oct-2015::17:10:17 ===
** Generic server yaws_server terminating
** Last message in was {setconf,
                       .........
** When Server state == {state,undefined,[],0,true}
** Reason for termination ==
** {badbind,[{yaws_server,start_group,2,
                      [{file,"src/yaws_server.erl"},{line,271}]},
         {lists,filtermap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1315}]},
         {yaws_server,init2,5,[{file,"src/yaws_server.erl"},{line,248}]},
         {yaws_server,handle_call,3,
                      [{file,"src/yaws_server.erl"},{line,314}]},
         {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,
                     [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},
         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,639}]},
         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to provide more of the fatal part of the error message, rather than truncating it.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The `ssl` application isn't running. Before calling `yaws:start_embedded/4`, start `ssl` like this:

```
application:ensure_all_started(ssl),
yaws:start_embedded(Docroot, SconfList, GconfList, Id)
```

If you're using an older version of Erlang that doesn't provide `application:ensure_all_started/1`, which is any version older than R16B02, you can start `ssl` like this instead:

```
[application:start(App) || App <- [crypto, public_key, ssl]],
```

Comment: After I add application:ensure_all_started(ssl), It works and no  any error message. Thank you very much